# Square thumbnails

Tags: typo3, frontend, typoscript

I want to generate a square thumbnail from a sourceimage for a TYPO3 gallery extension, but I don't find a way to do this. It can be a square section from the source image.

To decrease the image proportional to an thumbnail, i use the following function:

```
    function generateImg($w,$h,$fname,$dir,$class,$id){
    $imgTSConfig = array();
    $imgTSConfig['file'] = $dir.'/'.$fname;                         
    $imgTSConfig['file.']['maxW'] = $w;
    $imgTSConfig['file.']['maxH'] = $h;
    $imgTSConfig['stdWrap.']['addParams.']['class'] = $cl;
    $imgTSConfig['stdWrap.']['addParams.']['id'] = $id;

    $timg = $this->cObj->image($imgTSConfig); 
    return($timg);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$imgTSConfig['file.']['width'] = '120';
$imgTSConfig['file.']['height'] = '120c';
```

...instead of (or combined with) `maxH` and `maxW`. The 'c' parameter crops the image if it is to high.

[Source](http://www.elp.co.at/2010/06/17/cropping-of-images-in-typo3-with-typoscript/)

Comment: Ok, this is all? So easy? Nice! Thank you!

Comment: De nada. Maybe combining `minW` and `height` would be perfect here.